# Webpack library not defined

Tags: webpack

Hello i'm trying out webpack.
I have made a bundle and a vendor bundle.
In the vendor bundle i just have jquery for now.

Everything works fine when trying to call jquery in my bundle.
But i i make a script tag inside the head and try to call it it says "$ is not defined" also if i try with "jQuery"

**Webpack.config.js**

```js
var webpack = require('webpack');
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
var precss = require('precss');
var rucksackCss = require('rucksack-css');
var BrowserSyncPlugin = require('browser-sync-webpack-plugin');
// var node_modules_dir = path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
      app: "./src/bundle.js",
      vendor: ['jquery', 'gsap']
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/dist',
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test:   /\.css$/,
                loader: "style-loader!css-loader!postcss-loader"
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
      new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin(/* chunkName= */"vendor", /* filename= */"vendor.bundle.js"),
      new BrowserSyncPlugin({
          host: 'localhost',
          port: 3000,
          proxy: "mod.dev",
          files: ["dist/*js", './**/*.php']
          // server: { baseDir: ['public'] }
      }),
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: "jquery",
            jQuery: "jquery"
        })
    ],
    postcss: function () {
        return [autoprefixer, precss, rucksackCss];
    }
};
```

What am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to expose jQuery so it is available on the window using the [expose-loader](https://github.com/webpack/expose-loader):

```
module: {
  loaders: [
    { test: require.resolve("jquery"), loader: "expose?$!expose?jQuery" },
  ]
}
```